# Getting metadata from google drive file in c#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to get metadata's information about all of a Google Drive.
This is my code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        var clientId = "MyID";
        var secret = "MySecret";
    var service = GoogleDriveFileListDirectoryStructure.AuthenticateOauth(clientId, secret, "AppliUserAutor2");

        var allFiles = GoogleDriveFileListDirectoryStructure.ListAll(service, new GoogleDriveFileListDirectoryStructure.FilesListOptionalParms { Q = "('root' in parents)", PageSize = 1000 });
        GoogleDriveFileListDirectoryStructure.PrettyPrint(service, allFiles, "");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
internal class GoogleDriveFileListDirectoryStructure
        {                
            public static DriveService AuthenticateOauth(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName)

        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("clientId");
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientSecret))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("clientSecret");
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");

                // These are the scopes of permissions you need. It is best to request only what you need and not all of them
                string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };        //View the files in your Google Drive

                var credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/apiName");

                // Requesting Authentication or loading previously stored authentication for userName
                var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                             , scopes
                                                                                            , userName
                                                                                             , System.Threading.CancellationToken.None
                                                                                             , new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                // Returning the SheetsService
                return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Drive Oauth2 Authentication Sample"
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Create Oauth2 account DriveService failed" + ex.Message);
            throw new Exception("CreateServiceAccountDriveFailed", ex);
        }
    }

    public class FilesListOptionalParms
    {
        /// The source of files to list.
        public string Corpus { get; set; }

        /// A comma-separated list of sort keys. Valid keys are 'createdTime', 'folder', 'modifiedByMeTime', 'modifiedTime', 'name', 'quotaBytesUsed', 'recency', 'sharedWithMeTime', 'starred', and 'viewedByMeTime'. Each key sorts ascending by default, but may be reversed with the 'desc' modifier. Example usage: ?orderBy=folder,modifiedTime desc,name. Please note that there is a current limitation for users with approximately one million files in which the requested sort order is ignored.
        public string OrderBy { get; set; }

        /// The maximum number of files to return per page.
        public int PageSize { get; set; }

        /// The token for continuing a previous list request on the next page. This should be set to the value of 'nextPageToken' from the previous response.
        public string PageToken { get; set; }

        /// A query for filtering the file results. See the "Search for Files" guide for supported syntax.
        public string Q { get; set; }

        /// A comma-separated list of spaces to query within the corpus. Supported values are 'drive', 'appDataFolder' and 'photos'.
        public string Spaces { get; set; }
    }
    public static Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList ListAll(DriveService service, FilesListOptionalParms optional = null)
    {
        try
        {
            // Initial validation.
            if (service == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("service");

            // Building the initial request.
            var request = service.Files.List();

           request.PageSize = 100;

            //request.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id,name,size,description,createdTime,webViewLink)";

            // Applying optional parameters to the request.
            request = (FilesResource.ListRequest)SampleHelpers.ApplyOptionalParms(request, optional);

            var pageStreamer = new Google.Apis.Requests.PageStreamer<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File, FilesResource.ListRequest, Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList, string>(
                                               (req, token) => request.PageToken = token,
                                               response => response.NextPageToken,
                                               response => response.Files);

            var allFiles = new FileList();
            allFiles.Files = new List<File>();

            foreach (var result in pageStreamer.Fetch(request))
            {
                allFiles.Files.Add(result);
            }

            return allFiles;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Request Files.List failed.", Ex);
        }
    }
```

When I try to ask more information with this request :

```
request.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id,name,size,description,createdTime,webViewLink)";
```

I have only 29 results (allFiles) with all the needed information but in fact I have 1699 file.
When I don't specify any fields request I can list all the file but I only have ID and Name File.

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine. The way you rethrow the exception will clear the stacktrace - wich is about 90% of the relevant information - while also adding another layer. Here are two articles I link a lot on proper handling of exceptions: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: CAn you link where you got that code from please?

Comment: The code come from:  https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/9e512d95ef874d0c4dbc8d0783dcc4bc

Comment: @Ulixes if you are going to copy my Gist file you might as well read the tutorial I wrote that goes along with it https://www.daimto.com/list-all-files-on-google-drive/